# How to install Laravel on a web server using using softaculous in CPanel

Tags: php, laravel, webserver, cpanel

I want to install Laravel on my web server using softaculous available in my Cpanel but I get the following errors:

> *The following errors were found :*
>   Could not write the Configuration File app.php
>   Could not write the Configuration File composer.json.

What might I have done wrong?

Comment: Permissions of the directory in which you are trying install Laravel are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update some files within your laravel application. The problem is that you don't have the right to do so.

What you could do is: 
1. Check the file permissions and correct them.
2. Connect to your web server over ssh and try to install it.

Comment: How could OP correct the permissions? And how would you perform the installation over SSH? Can you give some examples?

Comment: OP could correct his permissions by connecting to his server with an SSH client like PUTTY for windows. And then using some commands correspondig to his operating system about checking and setting permissions on folders. Installing Laravel over SSH is possible with e.g. composer and using the Laravel install tutorial: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation